# RewriteCond with caret not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Here is an .htaccess file I am writing:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^api
RewriteRule (.+) test/$1.php [L]
```

Now, if I got to my browser and type in `/api/asdf`, I do not get `/test/api/asdf`. If I remove the caret, it works as expected. Also of interest, if I type `/bapi/asdf` in my browser, it does not work, which seems backwards because there is no caret.

Am I doing something wrong? How can I match the start of the `REQUEST_FILENAME` if caret does not work?

Answer (score 0):

The `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` variable isn't going to start with `api`. So the `^api` expression will never match. The request filename is the local file system path of what the request should map to.

You can try this instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(api.+) test/$1.php [L]
```

That matches requests that start with `/api`.

Comment: sory, api was just a made up name. the local file system path matches that path, so pretend like there is a directory in the root that is api.

Comment: @tau then you need a `/` right after the `^`. Assuming you're on linux or a Mac, the filesystem path will probably start with a `/`

Comment: i just tried that and it does not work, with or without the forward slash. i tried both ^/api and ^api/ and neither worked.